# Reading stream of Data using TIdIOHandlerStream and TIdTCPClient

Tags: delphi, c++builder, indy10, c++builder-10.2-tokyo, c++builder-tokyo

I have an app that needs to connect to a server using TCP/IP and then just wait for server to send data, and what ever server sends should be saved into a file.

Here is what I did:

The Header file

```cpp
#ifndef MainH
#define MainH
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <System.Classes.hpp>
#include <FMX.Controls.hpp>
#include <FMX.Forms.hpp>
#include <FMX.Controls.Presentation.hpp>
#include <FMX.StdCtrls.hpp>
#include <FMX.Types.hpp>
#include <IdBaseComponent.hpp>
#include <IdComponent.hpp>
#include <IdIOHandler.hpp>
#include <IdIOHandlerStream.hpp>
#include <IdTCPClient.hpp>
#include <IdTCPConnection.hpp>
#include <boost/scoped_ptr.hpp>
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
class TForm1 : public TForm
{
__published:    // IDE-managed Components
    TIdTCPClient *pTCP;
    TIdIOHandlerStream *IdIOHandlerStream;
    TButton *Button1;
    void __fastcall Button1Click(TObject *Sender);
    void __fastcall IdIOHandlerStreamGetStreams(TIdIOHandlerStream *ASender, TStream *&VReceiveStream, TStream *&VSendStream);
private:    // User declarations
    boost::scoped_ptr<TFileStream> mFile;
    boost::scoped_ptr<TMemoryStream> mMem;

    void __fastcall StopTcpClick(TObject* Sender);
public:     // User declarations
    __fastcall TForm1(TComponent* Owner);
};
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
extern PACKAGE TForm1 *Form1;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#endif
```

and the CPP file:

```cpp
include <fmx.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#include "Main.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.fmx"
TForm1 *Form1;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner) : TForm(Owner),
                            mFile(new TFileStream(L"C:\\IbsData.txt", fmCreate | fmOpenReadWrite | fmShareDenyWrite)),
                            mMem(new TMemoryStream())
{
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    pTCP->Connect();
    Button1->Text = L"Stop";
    Button1->OnClick = StopTcpClick;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::StopTcpClick(TObject* Sender)
{
    pTCP->Disconnect();
    Button1->Text = L"Start";
    Button1->OnClick = Button1Click;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::IdIOHandlerStreamGetStreams(TIdIOHandlerStream *ASender, TStream *&VReceiveStream, TStream *&VSendStream)
{
    VReceiveStream = mFile.get();
    VSendStream = mMem.get();
}
```

I have to note that `IdIOHandlerStream` has been set as the `IOHandler` of `pTCP`.

The problem is, I know server is sending lots of data, but nothing gets written into the file.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: After doing some more digging, I also realized `netstat` does not show any active connection. But if I disconnect the `IdIOHandlerStream` from `TIdTCPClient`, Then the connection shows up in `netstat`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You are using the wrong IOHandler class.

`TIdIOHandlerStream` performs I/O using `TStream` objects. It is typically used for replaying previously captured sessions for debugging purposes, without needing a physical connection to a real server.

You need to use `TIdIOHandlerStack` instead, which performs I/O using a TCP/IP socket connection. It is Indy's default IOHandler class, so you don't even need to create an instance of it <sup>1</sup>, `TIdTCPClient::Connect()` will create one internally for you if you do not assign your own.

<sup>1: unless you need more advanced usage, like connecting to a server through a proxy, etc, then you need your own instance so you can configure it as needed.</sup>

For what you are attempting, let `TIdTCPClient` use `TIdIOHandlerStack` and then you can call the `TIdIOHandler::ReadStream()` method after connecting to the server. Pass in a `TFileStream` for it to read into, and set its `AByteCount` parameter to -1 and `AReadUntilDisconnect` parameter to True so it will read continuously until the socket connection is closed.

Also, like most operations in Indy, `ReadStream()` blocks the calling thread until finished, so to avoid blocking your UI, you should call `ReadStream()` in a worker thread. But, if you don't want to use a thread, you can alternately put a `TIdAntiFreeze` component on your Form instead.